# Submitting current timestamp in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What is the method to submit a current timestamp directly on an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`? If I were running regular SQL, I would use the function `NOW()` for the specific SQL field on submission. How would I do that with CakePHP?

```
$this->Model->save($this->data)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In CakePHP, you can include the `NOW()` function unescaped by using `DboSource::expression`

```
$this->data['SomeModel']['your_datetime_field'] = DboSource::expression('NOW()');
$this->Model->save($this->data);
```

This is the preferred way of including MySQL functions in your saves.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-DboSource.html#_expression

Comment: so I would have to manipulate the posted data before saving it.

Comment: Yes. But it's just adding one more element to the array. Also, if you have fields in your table named `created` and `updated`, cakephp will automatically updated them on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, respectively. However, I prefer adding the element manually.

Comment: Whoops, make the `created` and `modified`

Comment: Don't downvote in silence. If there's a reason for doing it on an answer this old, please give it. Also don't downvote answers that were correct at the time of writing. Rather, comment that it should be updated and include that info (or directly edit if you possess the privilege).

Comment: If you get a E_STRICT error, try calling $this->Model->getDataSource()->expression('NOW()')

Answer (score 7):

if you add the created and modified columns in you table they will be automatically populated with current time stamp. If the case is different - i.e. you want to populate a field which later on you want to modify, probably using the edorian's solution is best.

Comment: This is the cake way and should be the preferred answer +1. If the OP is asking for a modifiable field, she should be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timestamp field to auto initialize and auto update

```
timestampfield TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html