# Add current timestamp at a fixture on CakePHP 2.0

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, timestamp, cakephp-2.0, fixtures

I am trying to test a Model and i need to insert into the 'created' field the current time-stamp.

I am using a Fixture for it but using 'NOW()' doesn't seem to work. It writes 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

This is my fixture record:

```
public $records = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'body' => 'esto es una prueba',
            'idUser' => 2,
            'created' => 'NOW()',
            'ip' =>'1.1.1.1',
         )
)
```

Any idea about this?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting current timestamp in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823169/submitting-current-timestamp-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$records`is a class property, you cannot use functions inside the definition.
If you want to use functions (like in your case `date()`or similar) you've to do it inside the `init` function like this:

```
public function init() {
  $this->records = array(
    // ...
    'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    // ...
  );

  // dont forget to call parent::init() if you're overwriting init().
  parent::init();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public $records = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'body' => 'esto es una prueba',
            'idUser' => 2,
            'created' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'), // in this case `created` must have to be a DATETIME type
            'ip' =>'1.1.1.1',
         )
);
```

**OR**

```
public $records = array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'body' => 'esto es una prueba',
                'idUser' => 2,
                'created' => time(), // in this case `created` must have to be a TIMESTAMP type
                'ip' =>'1.1.1.1',
             )
    );
```

Comment: None of them works. Test can not run. I have already tried it. Also, both of them shows semantic errors before running them.